# Retrieve same value from an indexed PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am doing an invoice to PO module. So, let's say inside an invoice, there are 3 products,

```
Product a => Vendor A 
Product b => Vendor B
Product c => Vendor A
```

I have an array which is passed from angularJS to PHP.

the array is called

```
 products
```

following code is inside my PHP page

```
$products = isset($post_data['products']) ? $post_data['products']:array();

if(count($products) > 0){
    foreach($products as $v){
         //following code is working, but it will create 3 new PO with 
         //the respective products. So if let's say there are 3 products, with 2 items with same vendor, and 1 with another vendor, 
         //it will insert 3 new PO. What I wanted is to create 1 PO with 2 items(same vendor), 1 another PO with different vendor
         $param = array(
            //po data to insert
         );
         $this->_model->add($param);
         $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

         $products_array = array(
           //purchased product
         );
         $this->generic_model->add($products_array);        
    }
}
```

here is the var_dump result from array which is passed to the PHP page(from var_dump($v))

```
  array (size=3)
        'id' => string '35'
        'vendor' => string 'Vendor 1' 
        'vendor_id' => string '5' 
    array (size=3)
        'id' => string '33' 
        'vendor' => string 'Vendor 2 ' 
        'vendor_id' => string '7' 
    array (size=3)
        'id' => string '34'
        'vendor' => string 'Vendor 2 ' 
        'vendor_id' => string '7'
```

As you can see from the var_dump result, there are 2 same vendors, which are Vendor 2.

So my problem is, how can I loop the array from the angularJS in my PHP, and then "group" it based on the same vendor? So by given previous example, how can I insert data into my db with following data

```
2 tables in my db, purchase_order and purchased_product
New PO with 2 items inside from Vendor 2, (1 purchase order row with 2 rows in purchased_product)
Another new PO with 1 item from Vendor 1, (1 purchase order row with 1 row in purchased_product)
```

Have been dealing with it quite a while, and still can't figure out how to do the array looping..

Thank you.. :)

Comment: you can group vendors on JS(client) side. Also, show how should look your *//code for inserting data into database*

Comment: Where are you getting the `PO 1` and `PO 2` from?

Comment: updated explanation and code :). please forgive me if I can't explain so well, I am a junior programmer which Is still working how to write codes ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code example does not demonstrate where you get the `PO 1` and `PO 2` keys from, so I cannot include this in a solution. Please feel free to update your question to clarify that.

To take a JSON structure as above and turn it into an array of "grouped" string values, as specified, you can try the following:

```
<?php

// firstly, just some boilerplate for this example

$json = <<<JSON
[
    {
       "id": "35",
       "vendor": "Vendor 1",
       "vendor_id": "5"
    },
    {
       "id": "33",
       "vendor": "Vendor 2",
       "vendor_id": "7"
    },
    {
       "id": "34",
       "vendor": "Vendor 2",
       "vendor_id": "7"
    }
]
JSON;

$data = json_decode($json, true); 

// now we can start extracting and grouping data

// assuming you are using >= 5.5 here
// `array_column()` extracts the values of all 
// sub-arrays with the `vendor` key into an array
$vendors = array_column($data, 'vendor');

// `array_count_values()` aggregates a count
// for each instance of each string in the array
// with the vendor as the key and a count as its corresponding value
$vendorCounts = array_count_values($vendors);

// map over the keys and values, creating an array
// of strings in the specified format
$vendorGroups = array_map(function ($vendor, $count) {
    return sprintf('%d items from %s', $count, $vendor);
}, array_keys($vendorCounts), $vendorCounts);

print_r($vendorGroups);
```

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 items from Vendor 1
    [1] => 2 items from Vendor 2
)
```

Documentation reference:

- [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)
- [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)
- [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sir, updated question and removed JSON. I replace it with var_dump from($v) hope it makes clearer to understand